# Login from on site into another with different domains and server

Tags: django, authentication, django-rest-framework

I'm using Django and I have the following case.

My **main website** on **dummy.com** has the normal login form from Django.
The Django application is providing an API.

I have a Single Page Application on another server with the domain auth.dummy.com

My SPA is using **JWT** to authenticate the user so he can be logged in into the page **auth.dummy.com** by using the API provided by **dummy.com**

How can I archive it that the user who logs in on the domain **auth.dummy.com** automatically gets logged in into the main website **dummy.com**?

But I always want to keep the default behaviour from Django so Users can log in into the site from the main domain as well and not only from **auth.dummy.com**

Is there a special name for this kind of authentication?
I'm confused by all this names: JWT, SSO, OAuth etc.

Answer (score 0):

Have your SPA set the session cookie at the same time you store the JWT. Also make sure to use the same SESSION_COOKIE_DOMAIN on both sites.